# pattern matching data sets without regexs

Tags: matching

i have a large data set, tcpdump capture file exported to text.

I want to find any like unknown pattern in the data set and return the fields
and data sorted. basically we wish to look for unknown "patterns" in the data set.

i know we can use a regex with like awk and grep, but from a pure research perspective, im given a data set 5Gb and 10Gb, in which i want to find unknown like matching patterns.... 
they could be from any field or data structure. Ive used wireshark in various modes to sort structures

Comment: From a research perspective I'm missing some input. If you want a program to find patterns you should at least specify some objectives or a rule that defines what a pattern is for you (and the program). Once you've set that up, you can start about figuring out how to define that definition in code and match it against your data set.

Comment: Maybe you could look into using splunk.

Comment: There in lies the issue....... the objective becomes find the unknown using like or sequential patterns, there is no "definition" of what we are looking for, we wish to find simple unknown matching patterns  or sequential patterns in random data. basically read the data set and tell me whats similar in it